# With Google Drive API V3, Why setting permission to a recently copied file causes 'File not found' error?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

The scenario is: with a OAuth 2.0 client created in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, I want to pick some file from a user Google Drive (user space) in G Suite Business and then **copy** it to some folder in a Team Drive of **another owner** and then **change the owner** of the recently copied file.

This last operation causes a *File not found* `error`. Even with this error the file is copied file and has the **ID** that response tells me that it does not exist. The code and stack follows:

```
const google = require('googleapis'); // https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2('client_id', 'client_secret', 'redirect_url');

oauth2Client.setCredentials({'access_token': '' ,'token_type': '','expiry_date': ''});

const sourceFileId = '';

const googleDrive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: oauth2Client
});

googleDrive.permissions.create({
    fileId: sourceFileId,
    resource: {
        role: 'reader',
        type: 'domain',
        domain: 'example.com',
    }
}, (error, permissionResponse) => {

    if (error) {

        console.log(error);

    } else {

        googleDrive.files.copy({
            fileId: sourceFileId,
            supportsTeamDrives: true,
            ignoreDefaultVisibility: true,
            resource: {
                description: 'Copy of a file from user to store in Team Driver',
                parents: ['_driveteam_folder_id_']
            }
        }, (copyError, copyResponse) => {

            if (copyError) {

                console.log(copyError);

            } else {

                console.log(copyResponse, copyResponse.id);

                // Even with this timeout the error occurrs
                // 1elLwBg0urdz5z23_83tjpDSBt7YxD1c8 is the copyResponse.id show in the error below
                setTimeout(() => {

                    googleDrive.permissions.create({
                        fileId: copyResponse.id,
                        transferOwnership: true,
                        resource: {
                            role: 'owner',
                            type: 'user',
                            emailAddress: 'someone@example.com'
                        }
                    }, (ownerPermissionError, ownerPermissionResponse) => {

                        if (ownerPermissionError) {

                            console.log(ownerPermissionError);

                        } else {

                            console.log({permissionResponse, copyResponse, ownerPermissionResponse});   

                        }

                    });

                }, 10000);

            }

        });

    }

});
```

> { Error: File not found: 1elLwBg0urdz5z23_83tjpDSBt7YxD1c8.
>       at Request._callback (googleapis\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\transporters.js:85:15
>       at Request.self.callback (node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>     code: 404,
>     errors:
>      [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'notFound',
>          message: 'File not found: 1elLwBg0urdz5z23_83tjpDSBt7YxD1c8.',
>          locationType: 'parameter',
>          location: 'fileId' } ] }

Comment: Can you try making it two separate requests? One request to copy the file. Validate if it exists. If it does, add permission.

Comment: In some terms are separated. I set this timeout just to give me time to check its existing directly in Google Drive and it does. Could you meaning to "separate" requests by reauthenticate again?